# How to color the edges of the graph that make the minimal spanning tree

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I have a complete graph G with 4 nodes. I need to colour the edges that make a minimal spanning tree. How can I do that with networkx and python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`networkx.draw`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) takes an optional `edge_color` keyword argument which allows you to specify the color of individual edges. Using the [`minimum_spanning_tree`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.mst.maximum_spanning_tree.html) function, we can color an edge red if it is within the minimum spanning tree, and black otherwise.

### Code

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(4)

mst = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)

edge_colors = ['red' if e in mst.edges else 'black' for e in G.edges]

nx.draw(G, edge_color=edge_colors)
```

### Output

[image]